# Select textarea, focus it and simulate pressing a space bar

Tags: javascript, html

When user clicks on an `img` i want to add it's `alt` value into `textarea` and add a space to it as if user pressed it himself but not like this `el.value += ' ';`

Code :

```
var chatInput = document.querySelector('textarea[data-a-target="chat-input"]'); //textarea selector
var chatSend = document.querySelector('button[data-a-target="chat-send-button"]'); 

emoteList.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName == 'IMG'){
        chatInput.focus();
        chatInput.value += e.target.alt;
    }
})
```

The text gets added into `textarea`, but `textarea` change event doesn't fire.

What would be the best way to do this? I have spent hours using both Javascript and jQuery to make it work using events but i can't get it right.

I tried `focusing` on `textarea` and using dispatch/fire event on `window` but it does nothing.

I tried firing `keypress` on `textarea` but it has no effect either.

Comment: Could you clarify the significance of `add a space to it as if user pressed it himself so not like el.value += ' ';`? That looks to be (basically) what you're trying to do here. (`img` elements don't automatically get their `alt`s added to `textarea`s on the page, so I don't know what you're expecting with `as if user pressed it himself`)

Comment: Programmatically changing the value of a control element does not trigger a change event. You've to trigger it manually, see [how to build an event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) and fire it.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't want to simply add a space to a string. I want to simulate a space bar keyboard press. It's the only option that i can think of to actually trigger a change event on textarea.

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is that change event is not triggering then you can manually trigger it by

```
    var e = $.Event( "change" );
    $("#altArea").trigger(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need jQuery for this - just use `chatInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`.

```js
const chatInput = document.querySelector('textarea');
chatInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
  console.log('saw a change');
})
const chatSend = document.querySelector('button'); 

document.querySelector('#emote-list').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target.nodeName !== 'DIV') return;
  chatInput.focus();
  chatInput.value += 'foo ';
  chatInput.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
})
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<div id="emote-list">click</div>
```

Comment: It gives me the same result. When i click on something text is being added but I can't "Send" it unless I type at least one character of my own.

Also, the value does not appear in between<textarea><textarea/> it does update with each character as i type though.

Comment: What do you mean, `Send`? That's the first time you've mentioned that, and it seems to be pretty different from figuring out how to trigger a particular `change` event attached to an element. (also, a textarea's value changing doesn't ever update its innerHTML)

Comment: Here is a [link](https://www.twitch.tv/oban_internet) if you wanna see what the chat looks like. I am desperate to fix this problem but personally i don't even know where to look. Maybe they are using a custom event?

Comment: Like I said, seems to be quite a different question from what the question you posted was asking...

Comment: I wanted to trigger a change because i thought that this will cause textarea to update but I guess that I was wrong.

Comment: I might be a little off, it's just that i haven't slept in awhile.